# Return array data as object

Tags: php, jquery, object

Im having a problem getting my desired output out of a function.  I see that its returning the proper data when i do a 'var dump'.  However, it either does not show anything or i'm getting invalid argument errors / 'Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string'.

Here is the function

```
     public function searchUser($name, $limit = 0) {
     return $this->_makeCall('users/search', false, array('q' => $name, 'count' => $limit));
     }
```

and my code is calling it like this:

```
    $usearch=$_POST['usersearch'];



    $result = $instagram->searchUser($usearch);
```

....

```
    <div id="searchresults">

    <h4> Search result for <?php
     echo $usearch;
 ?>
 </h4>


    <section id="list">
    <?php



    foreach ($usearch as $object) {
    print $object->username;
    }


    ?>

    </div>

  </div>
```

lastly, here is the var dump when i just call it that way:

```
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["meta"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["code"]=> int(200) } ["data"]=> array(50) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (6) { ["username"]=> string(6) "george" ["bio"]=> string(0) "" ["website"]=> string(0) "" ["profile_picture"]=> string(57) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg" ["full_name"]=> string(0) "" ["id"]=> string(7) "7693231" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#5 (6) { ["username"]=> string(9) "instagod7" ["bio"]=> string(28) "Graphic designer ðŸ« O.D.U." ["website"]=> string(0) "" ["profile_picture"]=> string(76) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_26017769_75sq_1358524943.jpg" ["full_name"]=> string(6) "George" ["id"]=> string(8) "26017769" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#6 (6) { ["username"]=> string(17) "georgetowncupcake" ["bio"]=> string(81) "Official Instagram account of Georgetown Cupcake | Home of TLC's DC CUPCAKES!" ["website"]=> string(32) "http://www.georgetowncupcake.com" ["profile_picture"]=> string(77) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_265095138_75sq_1391136095.jpg" ["full_name"]=> string(18) "Georgetown Cupcake" ["id"]=> string(9) "265095138" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#7 (6) { ["username"]=> string(11) "georgewbush" ["bio"]=> string(79) "43rd President of the United States and Founder of the George W. Bush Institute" ["website"]=> string(21) "http://bushcenter.org" ["profile_picture"]=> string(77) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_531790154_75sq_1377896593.jpg" ["full_name"]=> string(14) "George W. Bush" ["id"]=> string(9) "531790154" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#8 (6) { ["username"]=> string(11) "georgelopez" ["bio"]=> string(50) "New Saint George Episode April 10th on @FXNetworks" ["website"]=> string(26) "http://www.georgelopez.com" ["profile_picture"]=> string(76) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_38811207_75sq_1390655218.jpg" ["full_name"]=> string(12) "George Lopez" ["id"]=> string(8) "38811207" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#9 (6) { ["username"]=> string(14) "georgerauscher" ["bio"]=> string(33) "photography | munich - Impressum:" ["website"]=> string(31) "http://www.george.li/impressum/" ["profile_picture"]=> string(77) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_237349510_75sq_1391160241.jpg" ["full_name"]=> string(18) "George A. Rauscher" ["id"]=> string(9) "237349510" }
```

Comment: Is there a `json_decode` in there somewhere?

Comment: What exactly do you want to return as HTML? Each object's property?

Comment: `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` means that you are trying to echo `$object`. So you should re-check arrays/objects of your return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming the vardump if of the $result variable, the object array you want to iterate is contained within the data property:

```
foreach ($result->data as $object) {
    print $object->username;
}
```